# How to initialise and return an array in a c++ header file?

Tags: c++, return-value, header-files

I'm not very good with header files but I want to use a header file to read data from a file and return the data as a vector in the main cpp file.

Here is my readposcar.h file:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int add(void) {

    double a1x, a1y, a1z, a2x, a2y, a2z, a3x, a3y, a3z; // I want all this stuff in vector form
    int i;
    double scale;
    string line; stringstream dum;

    ifstream poscar ("POSCAR");
    for (i=1; i<=5; i++) {
        getline(poscar,line);
        if (i==2) {stringstream dum(line); dum >> scale;}
        if (i==3) {stringstream dum(line); dum >> a1x >> a1y >> a1z;}
        if (i==4) {stringstream dum(line); dum >> a2x >> a2y >> a2z;}
        if (i==5) {stringstream dum(line); dum >> a3x >> a3y >> a3z;}
    }

    vector<double> myvec(3);
    myvec[0] = a1x;
    myvec[1] = a1y;
    myvec[2] = a1z;
    return myvec;
}
```

Here is my .cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include "readposcar.h"

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    int nbasis = 2;
    int nkpts = 10;
    vector<double> myvec2(3);
    myvec2 = add();
    cout << "No. of k-points: " << nkpts << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This obviously does not work. Can someone please advise on what's wrong and what I need to do to make it work? I can only get it to work if I do return say myvec[2] in the .h file but not the entire array.

I don't mind having it as an array if vectors don't work. Is it perhaps possible to just initialise the array in the header file as a sort of global array and then simply call it in the .cpp file?

Here are the errors I get:

In file included from main.cpp:4:0:

```
readposcar.h: In function ‘int add()’:
readposcar.h:27:9: error: cannot convert ‘std::vector<double>’ to ‘int’ in return
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:12:15: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘myvec2 = add()’
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks for the quick replies everyone!.              std::vector<double> add(void) {
   ...
   return myvec;
}

Comment: You might live to regret putting "using namespace std;" in a header

Answer (score 2):

You should change return type of `add` from `int` to `vector<double>`

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning the correct type.  Try:

```
vector<double> add() {
   ...
   return myvec;
}
```

However I would personally pass a reference to the `vector` within the scope of the caller and return boolean success (optional):

```
bool add(vector<double> &myvec) {
   ...
   return true;
}
```

As that avoids copying the `vector` which *could* be expensive, unless the C++ compiler is able to use [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) to optimize the copy operation, in which case you can use the former method semantics.

(Thanks to @aryjczyk and @AlexB for pointing this last point out).

Comment: compiler will elide the copy, it's called RVO. and passing output arguments is ugly, avoid it when you can

Comment: No, no, no, no. If you are using a compiler that's not over 10 years old, you should absolutely return by value. It will either RVO or a move constructor.

Comment: Thanks guys; I've edited my answer to mention the use of RVO.

Answer (score 0):

1. parse the line after calling getline().
2. convert each parsed value to double.
3. call push_back on vector to add the double.

Also, consider passing a reference to vector.

so, the signature of your function would change to:

```
int add( std::vector<double> & values )
```

That way you will avoid unnecessary copying when returning from the function.

Comment: Nope. Go ahead and return by value.

Comment: @aschelper, like it or not, it's more efficient to use the reference than returning a vector by value. You cannot be 100% sure that compiler will perform the RVO. With the reference there is no doubt what will happen.

Comment: With C++11, you can be 100% sure that it will not call a copy constructor.